# Show that two balls are disjoint for metric in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis

For $0 < a < b$, let indicator function $\chi_{[0,a]}$ then we have:

$\left \| \chi_{[0,a]} - \chi_{[0,b]}  \right \|_{\infty}=\left \| \chi_{[a,b]}  \right \|_{\infty}=1$

Further more,for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}$, then  $\chi_{[0,a]}$ $\in$ $B_{\frac{1}{4}}(x_1)$  and $\chi_{[0,b]}$ $\in$ $B_{\frac{1}{4}}(x_2)$

where distance between two points $x_1,x_2$ is 1.

I want to show that $B_{\frac{1}{4}}(x_1) \cap B_{\frac{1}{4}}(x_2)= \varnothing$

I am trying to use triangle inequality to prove the claim by contradiction. Then, suppose that this is true, let for $c \in (a,b)$ we have indicator function $\chi_{[0,c]}$ :

$\left \| \chi_{[0,a]} - \chi_{[0,b]}  \right \|_{\infty}=\left \| \chi_{[0,a]} - \chi_{[0,c]} + \chi_{[0,c]} - \chi_{[0,b]}  \right \|_{\infty} \leq \left \| \chi_{[0,a]} - \chi_{[0,c]}  \right \|_{\infty} + \left \| \chi_{[0,c]} - \chi_{[0,b]}  \right \|_{\infty} = \left \| \chi_{[a,c]}  \right \|_{\infty} + \left \| \chi_{[c,b]}  \right \|_{\infty}=2$

which doesn't seem here to be contradiction?!

Can somebody help me what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y\in B_{\frac{1}{4}}(x_1) \cap B_{\frac{1}{4}}(x_2)$. Then
$$
\|x_1-x_2\|\le\|x_1-y\|+\|y-x_2\|<\frac12.
$$